# Including Exponents in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, math, implementation, equation, exponent

How do you implement exponents in JQuery?

I'm modifying this:

```
$.fn.sumValues = function() {
var sum = 0; 
this.each(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':input') ) {
        var val = $(this).val();
    } else {
        var val = $(this).text();
    }
    sum += parseFloat( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10 );
});
return sum;
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.price').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('span.total').html( $('input.price').sumValues() );
});
```

to calculate a more complex formula of summations from user input.

The formula itself is (a through g are user inputs):

Step 1) X=((1+(a/100))^b)*(c*12)

Step 2) X+d=e

Step 3) e-f-g=h

Can you help me implement this more effectively?

Comment: Please improve your titles in future questions for an improved community. Good titles include a verb like 'Including Exponents in jQuery' and makes the question more searchable for other users.

Answer (score 3):

```
var X = Math.pow(1+(a/100), b)*(c*12);

var e = X+d;

var h = e-f-g;
```

[**Math.pow(base, exponent)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) is used for exponential calculation.

To set above value to input for example

```
$('#mortgage').val(X);

$('#utilities').val(e);
```

and so on.

Comment: Ok, now how would I get it to return the values I need it to (X, e and h)?

Comment: I need it to spit out the values into html -- here's an idea of what I'm looking for: http://diawareness.com/mugplan.aspx

Comment: @derschwigg you have to set calculated value to input field like above