# How can I use an exponent in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple loan calculator using jQuery for practice. I have most of the code down, but am having trouble inserting the exponent for the formula. I am aware of the Math.pow, but not sure if I am implementing it properly. Here is the loan formula:

```
P ( r / 12 ) / (1 - ( 1 + r / 12 ) ^-m )

P = principal
r = interestRate
-m = loan term in months
```

Here is my code:

```
var months = ("#loanTerm" * -1);
var calc = Math.pow(1 + (interestRate / 12), months);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
Loan Term(Months): <input class="userInput" id="loanTerm" type='number'>
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong with the Math.pow, or if there is a way I am able to simply set the months to an integer, I'm relatively new to jQuery so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, what is `("#loanTerm" * -1);` supposed to do here? Would you mind posting a brief section of HTML that contains "loanTerm"?

Comment: This **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10803378/2065039)** might help you!!

Comment: This does not really have much relevance to jQuery. Maybe you should replace the tag by a JavaScript one?

Comment: You could change to `var months = parseInt($("#loanTerm").val()) * (-1);`

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the confusion, ("#loanTerm" * -1); is supposed to take the loanTerm, which should be set to months and turn it into a negative integer. Guruprasad Roa: I did tready that, however my code isn't working, which is what makes me think I'm using Math.pow incorrectly. cars10: sorry about that, updated it for you.

Comment: Demo for you [here](http://jsbin.com/paxojeyuwu/1/embed?js,console,output). You can adjust it if the formula needs tweaking.

Comment: Thank you so much, Drakes! That is not returning something instead of NaN. I still have some work today but this got me back on track!

Comment: How do I give you credit for the answer, Drakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the exchange of comments, I'm fairly sure the underlying question is how to access the value of a form input with jQuery.

In jQuery you can get the value of an `<input>` with

```
$("#loanTerm").val()
```

In vanilla JavaScript you can use

```
document.getElementById("loanTerm").value
```

You can then *explicitly* convert it to an integer and make it negative like so (in jQuery):

```
var months = parseInt($("#loanTerm").val(), 10) * (-1);
```

To test if `months` is `NaN` (the user didn't enter anything, or entered non-numeric data), you can use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Finally, here is a [testbed](http://jsbin.com/paxojeyuwu/1/embed?js,console,output) you can experiment with to confirm the equation is working as expected. I hope this helps.

Comment: Or just `var months = -$('#loanTerm').val();`

Comment: If you were really pedantic, you wouldn't be using `parseInt()` in that manner; keep in mind that `parseInt("0x30")` yields `48` unless you explicitly pass the radix for decimal.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Ah, thanks. I frequently neglect the radix in my quick demos. FWIW, without parseInt, your way returns 0 on no user input. My way returns NaN.

Comment: Good man :) yeah, not sure whether OP would *want* NaN in that case; surely, `parseInt()` is stricter.